# Friendly URL questions

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

So I got few questions.
Let's say, I got 2 types of links: (for now)
1. `test.com/?d=ID`
I want it to be like `test.com/{cat}/{title}` where `{cat}` and `{title}` will be searched in DB by ID supplied in `d`.
2. `test.com/?h=ID`
I want it to be like `test.com/{cat}` where `{cat}` will be searched in DB by ID supplied in `h`.
What rules for mod_rewrite will make server (apache) understand, that `test.com/?d=ID` should redirect to `test.com/{cat}/{title}`?
And if person came from link like `test.com/{cat}/{title}` from what I understood I just do something like

```
$vars=explode ("/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

Then query db with $vars[1] and $vars[2] and serve content if any (of course with sanitizing everything before running query. Do I understand concept right?

Comment: on apache it'd be mod_rewrite, of which there's plenty of examples on this site on how to do such urls. no idea on nginx.

Comment: The funny thing is that the question is already tagged with mod-rewrite so the answer is in the tag O_o

Comment: yea, that is mistake on my side.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at this article on [SitePoint](http://www.sitepoint.com/guide-url-rewriting/). All in all, you do not want to be exploding the URL to get the parameters. This will lead to problems.

Comment: I've read that article before. Also, why exploding URL can lead to problems? Like which for example?